# Angular 2 CORS issues

Tags: node.js, http, angular, post, cors

I have the following Angular 2 http request;

```js
const endpoint = '<auth_url>';
const body = {
  prompt: 'consent',
  grant_type: 'authorization_code',
  redirect_uri: '<redirect_url>',
  code: '<authorization_code>'
};

const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic <auth>');
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')

const options = new RequestOptions({ headers });

this.http.post(endpoint, body, { headers: headers })
.map(res => res.json())
.subscribe(
  data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)),
  error => console.error(JSON.stringify(error)),
  () => console.log('Request complete')
);
```

This is connecting to a `node-oidc-provider` which has been attached to an ExpressJS instance, the issue I am having is with CORS as the request ends up as OPTIONS on the server because of preflight. This shouldn't be the case as I have specified the `Content-Type` header as seen above. Annoyingly I am trying to figure out whether this is an issue with the server or my Angular2 code?

Would I need to explicitly enable CORS on an ExpressJS application and if not, why would setting the correct header on the POST have no effect?

Comment: CORS needs to be configured on the Server. There is nothing you can do in JS (and therefore Angular also can't). In some cases it can be worked around using JSONP but that's quite limited.

Comment: Thanks, please see my comment on the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to enable CORS on the server side. That is if you have control on the server.
Here are the Headers that should be returned from the server to enable CORS

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
```

You can share some details about your server like if you want to add these headers from the code or in the WebServer itself.

Regarding the question about the reason why setting the headers in the POST request has no effect. The browser issues an OPTION request before your XHTTP request to ask the permission from the server about accepting CORS.

So, if you have control on the server, then you can add the headers I mentioned before. If not, then you can use some browser plugins to overcome this check.

Here is how the network tab in the developer tools should look like

[image]

Comment: One thing, though if I make a curl request to this server I get the expected response and that is without setting a 'Content-Type' header, I can also set that header in POSTMAN and get the desired response. The node application is behind a NGINX instance with PhusionPassenger so I could add them there, right? What's odd is that this request works using the aforementioned techniques but not with Angular?

Comment: It is not working from angular as the "Browser" is doing the preflight itself. From curl or postman, the POST request is going directly to the server like any other request. CORS check is imposed by the browser. And yes, you can add them in the server directly as fixed headers. My recommendation is to add them from code to control it better.

Comment: For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests initiated from within javascript. Angular runs in the browser :)

Comment: You guys are awesome. Thanks for the help.. have a great weekend ;-)

Comment: I'm still getting an `OPTIONS` request show up and an empty response in Angular?

Comment: That is normal. If the `OPTIONS` request got a good response from the server, the browser will issue `POST` request after it. What is the final result? did you get a response successfully?

Comment: I don't have any handlers for an `OPTIONS` request and nothing happens after that. Funnily enough, I have added `CORS` on the NodeJS application and my error is as follows .. `"statusText":"Bad
            Request","headers":{"Content-Type":["application/json` ..

Comment: check the updated screenshot. for each `POST` and `GET` request there will be an `OPTIONS` request right before

Comment: I see, thanks. Does that mean that this doesn't have to be handled on the server, i.e. I have routes to handle `OPTIONS` requests?

Comment: I solved it, you guys sent me in the right direction. The first part of the solution was to enable cors on the server. Secondly as you might see in the question I am posting an object as the body, so that gave me the `Content-Type` error so I just had to construct my body to `var body = ['key=value', 'key=value'].join('&')` to get my desired response. Thanks for the help :-)